# User has 5 reputation, but looks like they should have 22

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, self-answer

I have a user on SQA stack exchange that shows as having 5 reputation. Their graph, their profile, everything.

Their profile shows four questions and two answers. All have 0 up and 0 down votes. Three of the questions have accepted answers. That should yield 6 reputation. One of the answers was flagged as accepted. This should yield an additional 15.

The initial 1 reputation, plus 6 from questions, plus 15 from the answer should be 22 rep. But the user only has 5. Is this a bug?

The user in question is https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/3208/engy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, they [answered their own question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/check-for-value-if-found-before-adding-it-to-my-drop-down-list/5277#5277), which doesn't give them the +2 for accepting, or +15 for an accepted answer.

So really they have (base 1 reputation) + (2 points for accepting answer) + (2 points for accepting answer) = 5 rep.

Answer (score 3):

[One of them was a self-answer.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/check-for-value-if-found-before-adding-it-to-my-drop-down-list)

Self accepted answers don't give rep either for accepting or for being accepted. So the user doesn't get the +2 or the +15.

(Although besides the point, self-accepts also don't get pinned above the other answers.)

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen that. Makes perfect sense now. I sense an incoming [status-by-design] tag coming.